# What is the longest word made with mostly affixes?

Tags: word, english

What is the longest word you can make that is mostly made up of affixes (prefixes and suffixes)?

For example,

> Retestings

would work, but it's not a long word.
The word has to have only one root word, and multiple affixes.
There is no right or wrong answer to this question. I just want to see how long of a word you can make.

Answer (score 2):

> **antidisestablishmentarianism** is a long one (28 letters)

Or its longer form,

> **antidisestablishmentarianistically** (34 letters)

---

> The root is "establish"
>
>  Prefixes: anti-, dis-
>
>  Suffixes: -ment, -ary, -an, -ism/-istically

Comment: Ah...brings me back to my school days.